# Fatal: Failed to write genesis block: can't start clique chain without signers

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I am trying to setup a local geth blockchain server but every time I attempt to execute I get the above error. I created the account first with the following command.

C:\private_chain>geth --datadir ./chaindata account new

Your new key was generated

Public address of the key:   0x6F963a9D9565473766CbfddaF744F343f726Fe14

I then take the address given and modify the genesis file seen below:

[image]

Bet I can't seem to get the genesis file to actually initialize as it says I can't without signers. I am new to this so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.